# Python3 Find value in a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I created a function where i add persons and their availability to a list called gamers.
I want the function to have two exceptions.
If the person forgets to add their name or their availability i will print: "Gamer missing critical information"

I also want to have an error if the name is already in the list and print: "This name already exists"

**However i cant seem to find a way to get the value dictionary["name"] within the list.**

*I also tried gamers[0]["name"] but that didnt work.*

```
gamers = []

def add_gamer(gamer, gamers):
    if gamer.get("name") and gamer.get("availability"):
        gamers.append(gamer)
    elif gamers["name"] in gamers:                      #Here is the problem
        print("This name already exists")
    else:
        print("Gamer missing critical information")
    return gamers

kimberly = {
    'name': "Kimberly Warner",
    'availability': ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"]
}
print(add_gamer(kimberly, gamers))

add_gamer({'name':'Thomas Nelson','availability': ["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Joyce Sellers','availability': ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Michelle Reyes','availability': ["Wednesday", "Thursday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Stephen Adams','availability': ["Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name': 'Joanne Lynn', 'availability': ["Monday", "Thursday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Latasha Bryan','availability': ["Monday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Crystal Brewer','availability': ["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'James Barnes Jr.','availability': ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Michel Trujillo','availability': ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]}, gamers)


add_gamer({'name':'Thomas Nelson','availability': ["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
print(gamers)

#this last line (which ads Thomas Nelson) should return: "This name is already in the list"
```

Comment: I found a typo. The elif line should be "elif gamer["name"] in gamers:" and not elif gamer(S). However this doesnt solve my problem

Comment: any particular reason why you are using a list of dicts rather than a dict of dicts?

Comment: No particular reason. I could change it into a dict. But it should also be possible with a list, no?

Comment: only have to check one entry when checking if the name exists, rather than searching the entire list. the ```dict``` class also handles missing keys and updating keys for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the order and check:

```
if any(g['name'] == gamer["name"] for g in gamers):
    print("This name already exists")
elif gamer.get("name") and gamer.get("availability"):
    gamers.append(gamer)
```

Comment: The name still pops up twice after switching the order.

Comment: Thanks Joep. What does the "any" command do?

Comment: @CallTheDay Google can explain way better than me ;), In short, I'm going over the items in the `gamers` list using list comprehension, and if any of the names match the `if` statement becomes true.

Comment: Alright i will do that. Thanks for the help. Very appreciated

Comment: @Joep--the any does essentially what MuhammedJaseem answer does in the for loop..

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are appending the element first and then checking if it exists. So, the efif part basically doesn't do anything. So, change the order of that.

```
gamers = []

def add_gamer(gamer, gamers):
    for gam in gamers:
        if gam['name'] == gamer['name']:#Here is the problem
            print("This name already exists")
            return gamers
    if gamer.get("name") and gamer.get("availability"):
        gamers.append(gamer)
    else:
        print("Gamer missing critical information")
    return gamers

kimberly = {
    'name': "Kimberly Warner",
    'availability': ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"]
}
print(add_gamer(kimberly, gamers))

add_gamer({'name':'Thomas Nelson','availability': ["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Joyce Sellers','availability': ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Michelle Reyes','availability': ["Wednesday", "Thursday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Stephen Adams','availability': ["Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name': 'Joanne Lynn', 'availability': ["Monday", "Thursday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Latasha Bryan','availability': ["Monday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Crystal Brewer','availability': ["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'James Barnes Jr.','availability': ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Sunday"]}, gamers)
add_gamer({'name':'Michel Trujillo','availability': ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]}, gamers)


add_gamer({'name':'Thomas Nelson','availability': ["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"]}, gamers)
print(gamers)

#this last line (which ads Thomas Nelson) should return: "This name is already in the list"
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. This was definitely a mistake in my code. However the problem still occurs after the switch

Comment: Really? It doesn't print anything after Michael Truijallo for me.

Comment: I switched the elif command with the if command so he checks if the name is in the list beforehand. But in my output i still see Thomas Nelson twice

Comment: If you try running the code i posted, you will see that only one Thomas Nelson is present

Comment: You are right. Your code works as well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

- Your `elif` condition is never hitting. (That's why you didn't get an error, otherwise `gamers["name"]` for a list would have given an error.
- Even if you correct the `if` order and even if you made it gamer['name'], you're inserting a `dict` in a `list` and then checking if `str` is in list.

You can define a function to search in list of dict by a given key-value pair.

```py
def search_list_of_dict(_list, _key, _value):
    return [el for el in _list if el.get(_key) == _value]
```

So your function definition becomes,

```py
gamers = []

def add_gamer(gamer, gamers):
    if gamer.get("name") and gamer.get("availability"):
        if search_list_of_list(gamers, 'name', gamer.get("name"):
            print("This name already exists")
            return False
        else:
            gamers.append(gamer)
            return True
    else:
        print("Gamer missing critical information")
        return False
```

Although, most importantly, you should really be using `dict`, since search in list is `O(n)` and search in `dict` is `O(1)`, and your code would simplify greatly as well.

Also, you don't need to return `gamers` since you are just appending to it. You can return a boolean to indicate whether the insertion was successful or not.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think i can continue with my program now :)